# Java error - The type List<E> is not visible - The type Map<K,V> is not visible

Tags: java, eclipse, web

I'm currently coding a website for a university project using java.
After coding almost everything I needed, this error began to show up on my screen. Here's an image of the error:

[image: Image 1: The type List<code><E></code> is not visible]

Not only that one, but this one too, on the same method.
Here's an image of the error:

[image: Image 2: The type Map<code><K,V></code> is not visible]

The errors is on the "executarRegras" method (code posted below).

My imports for the `java.util.List`, and java.util.Map are just fine, and both problems began showing up when I was coding the web part of the project (Servlet, ViewHelpers, JSPs).

And there are moments when I just clean my code and rebuild it, and those errors simply stop showing up and the code is not marked as an "error". (But then, if I clean and rebuild it once more, sometimes the class is marked as error again, or it just builds sucessfully. The error is just random.

I haven't found any solution for this, only things based on imports and changes on the java build path, but nothing works.

There aren't any other classes with errors or mismatches, this is the only class that I'm recently having trouble with.

I'm using:

- Eclipse Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
- Java: jdk-11.0.2
- Tomcat: v9.0 Server

**As requested, here is my Java Build Path:**

[image: JavaBuildPath - Source]

Here, in order for my "core" to exist, I need to make a dependency on the "dominio" project.
[image: JavaBuildPath - Projects]

[image: JavaBuildPath - Libraries]

[image: JavaBuildPath - Order and Export]

Also, if useful, here are the "core" project references:
[image: Project references]

### Code

Here's the code:

```
package LES1_2019.core.impl.controle;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

//myproject internal imports (all classes built sucessfully)

import LES1_2019.core.IDAO;
//import geral
import LES1_2019.core.IFachada;
import LES1_2019.core.IStrategy;
//import resultado
import LES1_2019.core.aplicacao.Resultado;
//import daos
import LES1_2019.core.impl.dao.CategoriaDAO;
import LES1_2019.core.impl.dao.ProdutoDAO;
import LES1_2019.core.impl.negocio.ProdutoMesmoNome;
import LES1_2019.core.impl.negocio.ValidarDadosCategoria;
//import regras de negocio
import LES1_2019.core.impl.negocio.ValidarDadosProduto;
import LES1_2019.dominio.Categoria;
import LES1_2019.dominio.EntidadeDominio;
import LES1_2019.dominio.Produto;


public class Fachada implements IFachada {
private Map<String, IDAO> daos;
private Map<String, Map<String, List<IStrategy>>> rns;
private Resultado objResultado;

 public Fachada() {
    daos = new HashMap<String, IDAO>();
    rns = new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<IStrategy>>>();

    CategoriaDAO objCategoriaDAO = new CategoriaDAO();
    ProdutoDAO objProdutoDAO = new ProdutoDAO();

    daos.put(Categoria.class.getName(), objCategoriaDAO);
    daos.put(Produto.class.getName(), objProdutoDAO);

    //criando objetos das classes de regras de negocio
    ValidarDadosProduto objValidarDadosProduto = new ValidarDadosProduto();
    ProdutoMesmoNome objProdutoMesmoNome = new ProdutoMesmoNome();
    ValidarDadosCategoria objValidarDadosCategoria = new ValidarDadosCategoria();

    //adicionando os objetos das classes de regras a array list de salvar produtos
    List<IStrategy> rnsSalvarProduto = new ArrayList<IStrategy>();
    rnsSalvarProduto.add(objValidarDadosProduto);
    rnsSalvarProduto.add(objProdutoMesmoNome);

    //adicionando os objetos das classes de regras a array list de salvar categorias
    List<IStrategy> rnsSalvarCategoria = new ArrayList<IStrategy>();
    rnsSalvarCategoria.add(objValidarDadosCategoria);

    //criando um hasmap das listas com as regras de negocio
    Map<String, List<IStrategy>> rnsProduto = new HashMap<String, List<IStrategy>>();
    Map<String, List<IStrategy>> rnsCategoria = new HashMap<String, List<IStrategy>>();

    //adicionando as operacoes que irao utilizar o map com a lista de regras
    rnsProduto.put("SALVAR", rnsSalvarProduto);

    rnsCategoria.put("SALVAR", rnsSalvarCategoria);
    rnsCategoria.put("ALTERAR", rnsSalvarCategoria);

    rns.put(Produto.class.getName(), rnsProduto);
    rns.put(Categoria.class.getName(), rnsCategoria);

}

private String executarRegras(EntidadeDominio entidade, String operacao) {
    String nmClasse = entidade.getClass().getName();
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();

       //this is where I get the first error type Map<K,V> is not visible
    Map<String, List<IStrategy>> regrasOperacao = rns.get(nmClasse);

    if(regrasOperacao != null) {

               //this is where I get the error type List<E> is not visible
        List<IStrategy> regras = regrasOperacao.get(operacao);

        if(regras != null) {
            for(IStrategy s:regras) {
                String m = s.processar(entidade);
                System.out.println(m);
                if(m != null) {
                    msg.append(m);
                    msg.append("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(msg.length()>0)
        return msg.toString();
    else
        return null;
}
```

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Don't link pictures and code, show them. This will make your post more readable and the chance to get an answer is higher.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so]! This is a programming site, not a photography site, so please, post your code and your errors, not photographs of your code and your errors. We want to copy&paste, read, and debug them, not critique their use of color and perspective. Also, please put them *in the question*, not on some external site which may go away at any time. Also, please make sure to construct a [mcve], i.e. an example of your problem that has the absolute minimum amount of code necessary to demonstrate your problem (I am guessing for this particular problem, that would be about 5 lines), …

Comment: … is complete and free-standing (i.e. does not require any external libraries, or if it absolutely *requires* external libraries, then make sure that those are easily available to any person who wants to answer your question, are easily installable, and document which exact versions and variants you are using), is *verifiable* in that it actually demonstrates the problem *and* allows us to see whether the problem goes away, and last but not least, is an faithful example of what your actual problem is.

Comment: Thanks JörgWMittag, nologin for the quick response and the help to improve my question. I made some editing and changed my question based on what you mentioned. Hope that's better. If there's something I can still improve, please let me know! :)

Comment: You can chage to reference how list how protected

Comment: How do you rebuild it (Maven, Gradle or by cleaning the projects)? Please show your Java Build Path.

Comment: @howlger I use the default Eclipse cleaner and builder. Actually, I use the clean option with the "Build automatically" funcionality. In this project I'm not using any kind of framework.

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónRapela I tried changing the declaration type of the map to protected instead of private, I even tried public, and it continues with the same error. Is that what you mentioned?

Comment: @GustavoMendes Yes , Do you have the open source code?

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónRapela Yes, I just uploaded everything to Git. Here's the link: https://github.com/gumenol/projeto_les.git

Comment: @GustavoMendes I review ...

Comment: It works for me, maybe it's because you're using Java 9? @GustavoMendes

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónRapela Really? I wil downgrade my execution environment on all projects and try again.
At first, I thought it was an error cause by the config of Deployment Assembly, or JavaBuildPath/References...
I'm gonna try it and get back here with the result.

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónRapela It worked! I downloaded the Java JDK version 8 and now the error is gone. Multiple cleans and rebuilds, even my tomcat server is working again, and tests via Postman work aswell. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'm glad !!! Happy coding !!! A pleasure!!! @GustavoMendes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was the change of version from Java 9 to Java 8.